# kibana3 does not load the page after changing time range.How to make it load on each time range change?

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok, grok, kibana-3

I am using kibana3 and could observe the behavior like after changing the time range the whole page does not refreshes automatically.

Need to take new link and load.

How to load dynamically on time range change ?

[image: Shanp-shot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether `Kibana 3` has the **auto-refresh** option on the right top corner of the page, which should be located right next to the *time picker* as per the latest versions. If so you could simply have an auto-refresh time interval so that it'll reload the data for you within the **time range** you've applied on the existing docs.

Hence you don't have to manually refresh the page or open it up on another tab.